# How to create a gallery of square windows for rectangular images in HTML CSS JS. Each window to have a separate modal image which pops up on clicking

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

So I have a few images which have different sizes and aspect ratios. I want to create a modal gallery of **square** thumbnails of those images in a grid form. When the user clicks on a thumbnail, the image should pop up on the screen with its original aspect ratio. Kind of like how twitter's **desktop** website displays your media thumbnails on your profile on the top right, next to your twitter banner.
*Now, I know how to do all of this except that I want each modal image to be contained(even cropped, and not overflowing) in a square thumbnail, and when the user clicks it, the actual image with its actual size/aspect ratio should pop up. I don't know how to create that square thumbnail modal window with the image not overflowing it.*

Comment: Do you mean actual size, or is it to be constrained eg by the width and or height of the viewport?

Comment: you can use object-fit css https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: it also is better to put here what you have made so far so can help you with what you struggle by editing the code

Comment: @AHaworth 
I want the images to appear as though square-cropped(and NOT stretched or squeezed), inside the small SQUARE modal window, and when the user clicks it, the actual image with actual size should pop up as overlay.
On twitter's desktop website, if you go to your profile page, you can see your media thumbnails gallery in the top right under search bar. I'm trying to make something like that.

Comment: Ok so as I understand it the pop up image has its natural size, even if that is bigger than the viewport?

Comment: @AHaworth
I want to create a gallery of small (let's say 60px w and 60px h) thumbnails of the images. When the user clicks a thumbnail, that image should pop up on the screen as overlay. Just like twitter **desktop** site's media thumbnails on top right of a profile page, to the right of the twitter banner.

Comment: object-fit cover for the thumbnails but I still am not sure what size you want the pop up to be.